# VBA to input a formula not working as expected

Tags: vba, excel

I've never used a VBA macro to input a formula. Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work? I was under the impression that the double quotes should fix my original problem of only showing up to the second quote - but it returns an error.

```
Sub Macro()

Worksheets("Summary").Range("H3").Formula "=EXACT(G3, COUNTIFS((INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("" '"", RIGHT(B3, LEN(B3) - FIND(""- "", B3) - 1), ""'!"", ""K:K""))), D3, (INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""'"", RIGHT(B3, LEN(B3) - FIND(""- "", B3) - 1), ""'!"", ""g:g""))), E3, (INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""'"", RIGHT(B3, LEN(B3) - FIND(""- "", B3) - 1), ""'!"", ""j:j""))), F3))"

End Sub
```

Comment: @timthebomb is correct. you need to make the `.Formula` = to the string containing your formula. You are also correct about double quotes in the code producing single quotes in the cell. eg `""text""` becomes `"text"` in the cell's value. I put your formula in a cell but get a `#VALUE!` error...hopefully because my sheet doesn't have the correct data in G3, D3, B3, etc. If you still get an error after implementing timthebomb's fix, please tell us what the error is because "returns an error" isn't really descriptive.

Comment: Eeek! 3 INDIRECT functions in a single formula. I hope you have a good reason for that.

Comment: Haha @ThunderFrame I definitely don't besides a lack of knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify the formula to add a "=" before the formula begins.

```
Worksheets("Summary").Range("H3").Formula = "=EXACT(G3, COUNTIFS((INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("" '"", RIGHT(B3, LEN(B3) - FIND(""- "", B3) - 1), ""'!"", ""K:K""))), D3, (INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""'"", RIGHT(B3, LEN(B3) - FIND(""- "", B3) - 1), ""'!"", ""g:g""))), E3, (INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""'"", RIGHT(B3, LEN(B3) - FIND(""- "", B3) - 1), ""'!"", ""j:j""))), F3))"
```